# Wordpress. Images not showing up in Google Chrome

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

So if you take a look at the website I am currently developing.
Particularly in the `footer` section of the website.

http://yourfitrepublic.com/

In Google Chrome, I am not able to see my picture in `footer`, but the rest are shown(they come with the template) It all is displayed in Safari for instance, but not in Chrome.

So the problem is with the pictures I have uploaded via ftp.

I have tried, disabling all of my extension, launching in incognito mode, checking the permissions, javascript and images are enabled too ... nothing helps.

Any suggestions?

P.S. If you paste this link in Safari, it will display and image, but not in Chrome, or Firefox.
http://yourfitrepublic.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/biceps-right.png

I am developing a child theme from Cherry Framework.

Comment: They don't show in Firefox either with the error "could not load images".

Comment: great! now, more issues! Funny fact, it works in opera mobile... but not on safari on my iPad, seriously... I just upload them via ftp and reference them via `<img`

Comment: Delete your cache in Safari and tell us if they still show up after.

Comment: Done, still the same, works on safari...

Comment: It's serving something at that address for the images, and the correct mime-type, just not an image. I don't understand that.

Comment: @Rob, yes I have seen that, if I go to host's control panel and see the properties of my images it says type: image/x-generic, so do the rest(default ones)

Comment: The image is probably corrupted. Try to open and re-save the image in a image editor.

Comment: If it is corrupted, why does it work in Safari?

Comment: very useful comment @Akash

Comment: it can be corrupted try re exporting image and upload new one

Comment: Firefox says it cannot display image because it contains errors

Comment: it doesn't load image in safari also. I installed last version of safari which came out for windows. Which version are you using and os?

Comment: hmm yes, it does! I was making them in Photoshop 6, wonder why...

Comment: it does like in working now?

Comment: yes, after I have reviewed most of my images, they are corrupt. So what I was doing is drawing them in PS6, and uploading via Sublime SFTP. Don't know why this has happened, now i have to make them all over again.... thank you for the help! everyone